# Nodejs connected to Heroku with Postgres - Select query doesn't display data

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

My app is connected to Heroku with Postgres. All what my app is displaying is 'Wassup'. In my heroku logs however I can see the content of my table 'users'.

How can i display it on my page?

logs :

```
2020-05-19T15:30:34.072537+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id":1,"name":"Athlestan","joined":"2020-05-19T08:42:12.705Z","lastvisit":null,"counter":0}
2020-05-19T15:30:34.072640+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id":2,"name":"Ragnar","joined":"2020-05-19T08:42:12.705Z","lastvisit":null,"counter":0}
2020-05-19T15:30:34.072716+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id":3,"name":"Rollo","joined":"2020-05-19T08:42:12.705Z","lastvisit":null,"counter":0}
2020-05-19T15:30:34.072832+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id":4,"name":"Lagertha","joined":"2020-05-19T08:42:12.705Z","lastvisit":null,"counter":0}
2020-05-19T15:30:35.232356+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-19T15:30:35.799999+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=herocave.herokuapp.com request_id=757c768a-8936-492a-a06f-f231dc05e7bd fwd="77.237.15.75" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=149 protocol=https
2020-05-19T15:30:37.500551+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=herocave.herokuapp.com request_id=70bfc824-defa-4a45-8fa7-5c7728c56faf fwd="77.237.15.75" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=205 protocol=https
```

index.js :

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const Client = require('pg').Pool 


app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.send("Wassup!");
});


const client = new Client({
connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
})

client.connect();

client.query('SELECT * FROM users;', (err, res) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  for (let row of res.rows) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
  }
  client.end();
});

app.listen(port);
```

index.js added new function :

```
const getUsers = (req, res) => {
    console.log('Fetching data ...');
    client.query('SELECT * FROM public."Users"', (error, res) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        console.log('Data aquired ...');
        for (let row of res.rows) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: What did you *think* would happen? Your database query is *outside* of the route handler, it happens only once when the app starts.

Comment: I am just learning this, how can I display it then?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. If you want the GET request to `/` to return a list of users, then that database code needs to be **inside the handler**, and you'll need to e.g. `res.json(rows)` instead of just logging it.

Comment: I've wrote some code but it's to long to paste it here, should I make another post or edit this one?

Comment: If there's a problem with that code, cut it down to a [mre] and post it here.

Comment: [Edit] the question.

Comment: ...with what outcome? Some obvious problems are that: 1. you're defining a function but never calling it; 2. you're shadowing res (...twice); and 3. you never respond to the request.

Comment: App crashes at .../db. Should I delete function(req, res) and instead put there getUsers?

Comment: `getUsers` is already a function that takes a `req` and a `res`, so that might be a start...

Comment: I did something like that ```app.get("/db", getUsers {
 const getUsers = (req, res) => { ...``` But I am missing ) after argument list, its frustrating

Comment: That's not valid syntax. I would strongly recommend getting a basic grasp of JS and ES6 syntax before trying to add Express and other frameworks on top.

Comment: I have added a new function, hope it's not dramatic, how can I use it now in ``` app.get("/db" ... ?

Comment: That makes even less sense. What error with *defining* the function are you trying to catch, for example? I would suggest structured tutorials rather than trial and error.

Comment: So const getUsers is a function right? so then i dont need to create a function getThemUsers right? so now I only need to put this function inside app.get("/db" .... ?